# duplication service and synchronized

Tags: java, android, synchronized

Start TimeThread.java inside the Service.java
Problems occur when Service.java is runs duplicated.

Why 'isWait' value is true in 'Log.d("isRun1")'  and false in 'Log.d("isRun2")'?

i wonder about 'duplicate running of service' and 'synchronized'.

my code is:

Service.java

```
thread.pauseNrestart(false);
```

Thread.java

```
    public class TimeThread extends Thread {

Handler handler;
boolean isRun = true;
boolean isWait = false;

public TimeThread(Handler handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
}

public void pauseNResume(boolean isWait) {

    synchronized (this) {

        this.isWait = isWait;
            *Log.d("isRun1 :" + isRun + "");*
        notify();
    }
}

public void run() {
    while (isRun) {
         *Log.d("isRun2 :" + isRun + "");*
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        if (isWait) {
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    wait();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain lines of code may be reordered when optimisations take place:
- the compiler optimises code when compiling, by reordering things; 
- the JVM may dynamically optimise code by reordering things;
- hardware might optimise performance by reordering thing.

So the section of code:

```
this.isWait = isWait;
*Log.d("isRun1 :" + isRun + "");*
```

Might have the lines switched.

This may also come down to a visibility issue. It may be that sometimes effects don't become visible to other threads.

When checking your while loops, you are not in a synchronized section, so things can change in the mean time if `pauseNResume` is called elsewhere. As mentioned, these changes may also not be immediately visible to the thread.

Try declaring isRun and isWait as volatile? Volatile will guarantee that reads and writes to that variable will not be reordered. This will fix the problem for if the lines are switched of the above code section I pointed out, so then the print will always happen after the `isWait` variable is changed.

However, for the way you are using these booleans in your while loop condition checking, I would suggest you also use [AtomicBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) instead of normal booleans.

Comment: Not too sure of what is asked by the section of the question "duplicate running of service"... I think that might be something to do with Android - my knowledge about Android is limited. The above answer relates to concurrency in Java.

Comment: I can think more about it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @mmoa I reread your question. If "duplicate running of service" just means that more than one thread is running (You said: "Start TimeThread.java inside the Service.java"). One thread alone would not have problems, but two threads may change things which influence the other, or make changes that the other doesn't see because of concurrency visibility issues.  You might also find [Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) useful instead of busy loops to check for running/waiting

Comment: I thought it was a problem between multiple services and synchronizations. However, Occurs when one thread is restarted while one thread is in operation. Thank you for your answer.